# Wordpress remove class="the_content_wraper"

Tags: wordpress

I want my wordpress site to be fullscreen, but I have a white border on the left
and on the rigt side.

It`s caused by: class="the_content_wraper"
Is there a possibility to remove it with css code?

```
<div class="section_wrapper">
  <div class="the_content_wrapper">
    <iframe src="https://www.xxxxx.xx" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this is a standard post page, on the UI admin panel there is an option on the right for page width. Change this to to something wider. If this question relates to plugins, then there are jquery options and wordpress hooks/filters.

Comment: You need to post the CSS of the affecting classes.

Comment: Sorry I`m new to wordpress, what do you mean with affecting classes? I only know that if I use the inspect tool in firefox and delete the <div class="the_content_wrapper"></div> the white borders disappear.

Comment: Yes this would be much easier to fix if you provided a link. What's probably going on is that is it sat a width on the_content_wrapper and the white is shining through from the element below. You could try changing the background color on parents or forcing 100% width on the_content_wrapper.

Comment: The information you've provided doesn't help. Either post a link or something.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked:

```
.section_wrapper, .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    content-wraper: 0px;
}

.section_wrapper{
padding-left: 0px !important;
padding-right: 0px !important;
margin:0px;
}

.the_content_wrapper{
margin:0px;
}
```